# Pandas returning the CIDR if the boolean result is true

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with several pandas dataframes.  df1 has IP address ranges and df2 has IP addresses.  This code correctly labels with a boolean result whether any IP in a df column matches any CIDR in a df column.  I am running into issues with grabbing the CIDR range instead of return the boolean result if it is true.

```
import pandas as pd
import netaddr
from netaddr import *
```

Create range dataframe

```
a = {'StartAddress': ['65.14.88.64', '148.77.37.88', '65.14.41.128','65.14.40.0', '208.252.49.240','12.9.27.48','107.135.41.16','47.44.167.240'],
 'EndAddress': ['65.14.88.95', '148.77.37.95','65.14.41.135','65.14.40.255', '208.252.49.247','12.9.27.63','107.135.41.23','47.44.167.247']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
#Convert range to netaddr cidr format
def rangetocidr(row):
    return netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(row.StartAddress, row.EndAddress)    

df1["CIDR"] = df1.apply(rangetocidr, axis=1)
df1["CIDR"].iloc[0]
```

Create ip dataframe

```
b = {'IP': ['65.13.88.64','148.65.37.88','65.14.88.65','148.77.37.93','66.15.41.132', '208.252.49.247','208.252.49.248','12.9.27.49']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=b)

#Convert ip to netaddr format
def iptonetaddrformat (row):
    return netaddr.IPAddress(row.IP)

df2["IP_Format"] = df2.apply(iptonetaddrformat, axis=1)
df2["IP_Format"].iloc[0]

ip = pd.DataFrame(df2.IP.str.rsplit('.', 1, expand=True))
ip.columns = ['IP_init', 'IP_last']

start = pd.DataFrame(df1.StartAddress.str.rsplit('.', 1, expand=True))
start.columns = ['start_init', 'start_last']

end = pd.DataFrame(df1.EndAddress.str.rsplit('.', 1, expand=True))
end.columns = ['end_init', 'end_last']

df = pd.concat([ip, start, end], axis=1)

index = []
for idx, val in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    for i in range(df.start_init.count()):
        if df.loc[idx, 'IP_init'] == df.loc[i, 'start_init']:            
            if df.loc[idx, 'IP_last'] >= df.loc[i, 'start_last'] and df.loc[idx, 'IP_last'] <= df.loc[i, 'end_last']:
                index.append(idx)
                break

df2['IN_CIDR'] = False

df2.loc[index, 'IN_CIDR'] = True
```

This correctly labels whether the IP from df2 falls into a range in df1 with a boolean answer True or False.

```
    IP             IP_Format      IN_CIDR
0   65.13.88.64    65.13.88.64    False
1   148.65.37.88   148.65.37.88   False
2   65.14.88.65    65.14.88.65    True
3   148.77.37.93   148.77.37.93   True
4   66.15.41.132   66.15.41.132   False
5   208.252.49.247 208.252.49.247 True
6   208.252.49.248 208.252.49.248 False
7   12.9.27.49     12.9.27.49     True
```

I would like to replace the `True` entries with the correct CIDR in a `df2` column **or** IP Range in 2 `df2` columns.  An example the desired output would be:

```
    IP             IP_Format      IN_CIDR
0   65.13.88.64    65.13.88.64    False
1   148.65.37.88   148.65.37.88   False
2   65.14.88.65    65.14.88.65    [65.14.88.64/27]
3   148.77.37.93   148.77.37.93   [148.77.37.88/29]
4   66.15.41.132   66.15.41.132   False
5   208.252.49.247 208.252.49.247 [208.252.49.240/29]
6   208.252.49.248 208.252.49.248 False
7   12.9.27.49     12.9.27.49     [12.9.27.48/28]
```

I have tried `df2.loc[index, 'IN_CIDR'] = df1.loc[index,'CIDR']` but this is just giving me the CIDR from df1 in the index position and not matching it to the ip that is in the CIDR range.

Comment: check out [`cyberpandas`](https://cyberpandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for native support of ip addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using this way:

```
a = {'StartAddress': ['65.14.88.64', '148.77.37.88', '65.14.41.128', '65.14.40.0', '208.252.49.240', '12.9.27.48',
                      '107.135.41.16', '47.44.167.240'],
     'EndAddress': ['65.14.88.95', '148.77.37.95', '65.14.41.135', '65.14.40.255', '208.252.49.247', '12.9.27.63',
                    '107.135.41.23', '47.44.167.247']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

# Convert range to netaddr cidr format
def rangetocidr(row):
    return netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(row.StartAddress, row.EndAddress)

df1["CIDR"] = df1.apply(rangetocidr, axis=1)

b = {'IP': ['65.13.88.64', '148.65.37.88', '65.14.88.65', '148.77.37.93', '66.15.41.132', '208.252.49.247', '208.252.49.248', '12.9.27.49']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=b)

# Convert ip to netaddr format
def iptonetaddrformat(row):
    return netaddr.IPAddress(row.IP)

df2["IP_Format"] = df2.apply(iptonetaddrformat, axis=1)


df2['IN_CIDR'] = False

for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    ip = row['IP']
    for j, r in df1.iterrows():
        subnet = str(r['CIDR'][0])
        if ip_in_subnetwork(ip, subnet):
            df2.loc[i, 'IN_CIDR'] = '['+ subnet + ']'
print(df2)
```

output:

```
               IP       IP_Format                           IN_CIDR
0     65.13.88.64     65.13.88.64                             False
1    148.65.37.88    148.65.37.88                             False
2     65.14.88.65     65.14.88.65                  [65.14.88.64/27]
3    148.77.37.93    148.77.37.93                 [148.77.37.88/29]
4    66.15.41.132    66.15.41.132                             False
5  208.252.49.247  208.252.49.247               [208.252.49.240/29]
6  208.252.49.248  208.252.49.248                             False
7      12.9.27.49      12.9.27.49                   [12.9.27.48/28]
```

and this is the function i call to know if IP is in Subnet:

```
import netaddr as netaddr
import socket
import binascii

def ip_in_subnetwork(ip_address, subnetwork):

    """
    Returns True if the given IP address belongs to the
    subnetwork expressed in CIDR notation, otherwise False.
    Both parameters are strings.

    Both IPv4 addresses/subnetworks (e.g. "192.168.1.1"
    and "192.168.1.0/24") and IPv6 addresses/subnetworks (e.g.
    "2a02:a448:ddb0::" and "2a02:a448:ddb0::/44") are accepted.
    """

    (ip_integer, version1) = ip_to_integer(ip_address)
    (ip_lower, ip_upper, version2) = subnetwork_to_ip_range(subnetwork)

    if version1 != version2:
        raise ValueError("incompatible IP versions")

    return (ip_lower <= ip_integer <= ip_upper)

def ip_to_integer(ip_address):

    """
    Converts an IP address expressed as a string to its
    representation as an integer value and returns a tuple
    (ip_integer, version), with version being the IP version
    (either 4 or 6).

    Both IPv4 addresses (e.g. "192.168.1.1") and IPv6 addresses
    (e.g. "2a02:a448:ddb0::") are accepted.
    """

    # try parsing the IP address first as IPv4, then as IPv6
    for version in (socket.AF_INET, socket.AF_INET6):

        try:
            ip_hex = socket.inet_pton(version, ip_address)
            ip_integer = int(binascii.hexlify(ip_hex), 16)

            return (ip_integer, 4 if version == socket.AF_INET else 6)
        except:
            pass

    raise ValueError("invalid IP address")

def subnetwork_to_ip_range(subnetwork):

    """
    Returns a tuple (ip_lower, ip_upper, version) containing the
    integer values of the lower and upper IP addresses respectively
    in a subnetwork expressed in CIDR notation (as a string), with
    version being the subnetwork IP version (either 4 or 6).

    Both IPv4 subnetworks (e.g. "192.168.1.0/24") and IPv6
    subnetworks (e.g. "2a02:a448:ddb0::/44") are accepted.
    """

    try:
        fragments = subnetwork.split('/')
        network_prefix = fragments[0]
        netmask_len = int(fragments[1])

        # try parsing the subnetwork first as IPv4, then as IPv6
        for version in (socket.AF_INET, socket.AF_INET6):

            ip_len = 32 if version == socket.AF_INET else 128

            try:
                suffix_mask = (1 << (ip_len - netmask_len)) - 1
                netmask = ((1 << ip_len) - 1) - suffix_mask
                ip_hex = socket.inet_pton(version, network_prefix)
                ip_lower = int(binascii.hexlify(ip_hex), 16) & netmask
                ip_upper = ip_lower + suffix_mask

                return (ip_lower,
                        ip_upper,
                        4 if version == socket.AF_INET else 6)
            except:
                pass
    except:
        pass

    raise ValueError("invalid subnetwork")
```

Comment: This is cool @Frenchy but I am running into `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

Comment: are yiu sure to take my last program i have edited it

Comment: Thank you @Frenchy I am going to try this.

Comment: this is what I was looking for!  Thank you!